# MAximDL plugin fails accessing filesystem

Tags: vb.net, filesystems, variant, class-library

I want to write the x,y, coordinates of a dragRectangle to a certain line in a text file(help.txt) by executing a plugin dll. Compilation runs fine. Writing is executed by sub ChangeFile. The plugin is started from the application MaximDL. The addition to the values of the image pixels works but other action do not.

From MaxIm documentation:
Definition DragRectangle
Property Document.DragRectangle (Variant)
Syntax Document.DragRectangle [ = variant ]
DragRectangle returns an array of four values which report the upper left and lower right corners of the current drag rectangle. The order of the data in the array is X1, Y1, X2, Y2.  Although DragRectangle is inherently an array, it is not possible to subscript it directly from Visual Basic or scripting environments. Instead, you must assign it to a local variable first, and access the individual coordinates from the copy
For some reason access to an existing file (help.txt) does not work at all. Also no runtime error message in case the file does not exist.
What is wrong? Is the way to extract the values of DragRectangle correct?

```
Imports System.IO
```

<ComClass(PlugIn.ClassId, PlugIn.InterfaceId, PlugIn.EventsId)>
Public Class PlugIn

#Region "COM GUIDs"
' These  GUIDs provide the COM identity for this class
' and its COM interfaces. If you change them, existing
' clients will no longer be able to access the class.
Public Const ClassId As String = "a1524f94-e3ce-4438-9671-bca0c39d4532"
Public Const InterfaceId As String = "cb83c68c-3ed9-40e2-8df2-639264b7ffbc"
Public Const EventsId As String = "73265d4c-16b5-4b3e-bd1a-34eabbd8ae77"
Dim frm1 As Form1 '<---- simple form added
' Plugin.ComClassAttribute(ClassID,InterfaceID,EventsID)
#End Region

```
' A creatable COM class must have a Public Sub New() 
' with no parameters, otherwise, the class will not be 
' registered in the COM registry and cannot be created 
' via CreateObject.
Public Sub New()
    MyBase.New()
    MsgBox(" Plugin Constructor NEW executed")

End Sub

Public Sub DoModal(ByVal Doc As MaxIm.Document)

    Dim Image(,) As Single ' Addition of 100 to the pixels
    Image = Doc.ImageArray
    Dim W, H, I, J As Integer
    W = Image.GetLength(1)
    H = Image.GetLength(0)
    For I = 0 To H - 1
        For J = 0 To W - 1
            Image(I, J) = Image(I, J) + 100 'this works
        Next
    Next
    Doc.ImageArray = Image
    'just for testing
    System.IO.File.Delete("C:\_Skripts\help.txt") ' <- not working
    frm1.Show()  '<--- also not working

    Dim T(3) As Integer ' Array to receive data   
    Dim SetArr(3) As Integer
    SetArr(0) = 10
    SetArr(1) = 10
    SetArr(2) = 200
    SetArr(0) = 200
    Doc.DragRectangle = SetArr '<- trying to set a rectangle inthe view
    Dim x_low, y_low, x_high, y_High
    T = Doc.DragRectangle
    x_low = T(0)
    y_low = T(1)
    x_high = T(2)
    y_High = T(3)
    ChangeFile()

End Sub

Public ReadOnly Property Name() As String
    Get
        Return "Add Constant 100 .NET"
    End Get
End Property

Public Sub ChangeFile()
    
    Dim newfile As New List(Of String)()

    For Each line As String In System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("C:\_Skripts\help.txt")
        Dim matchFound As Boolean
        matchFound = line.Contains("x:")

        If matchFound Then
            newfile.Add(line & vbNewLine & "x: TEXT ADDED")
        Else
            newfile.Add(line)
        End If

    Next
    System.IO.File.Delete("C:\_Skripts\help.txt")
    System.IO.File.WriteAllLines("C:\_Skripts\help.txt", newfile.ToArray())
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: Struggling to follow your question.  Maybe to simplify it, are your perhaps asking how to serialise and deserialise an array to/from a string?

Comment: I try to split it to simpler:
1st question: Why does the plugin dll work with modifying the image but refuses to delete a file? Please see arrows in the code.
I need to get some coordinates and write them to a certain position in a text file.
2nd question: Is the way correct to deal with variants which comes from the MaxIm API. Please see the excerpt from the API doc.

Comment: Added a simple form to the code. Compiles fine, but no form is shown. With VB6 it was possible to run a form from the plugin. Is there a difference between Win 7 and Win 10 concerning dlls ?